# Eclipse "run as android" does nothing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, galaxy

I've turned the internet upside down and looked into Google's official tutorials looking for an answer, but just couldn't find anything that actually solve my problem.

After installing everything and connecting my Galaxy S2 to the PC, clicking on "Run as -> Android application" just DOES NOTHING.

I got stuck [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html)

Comment: Also, do you see any error on logcat ?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse with the Android plugin? or did you download the ADK from Google? It used to be that you had to tell Eclipse where your Android folder and tools were, and if that wasn't set up I bet it would do nothing

Comment: Also, have you downloaded the Android tools runtime libraries for the platforms you are building for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you first have to create an AVD from the AVD manager. Then go the project properties - android - set the version. Run the project - select run as android application. You could also change the run configurations and set the default AVD that you want to use.

For running on the device, goto run configurations, select your project from the pane on the left - goto target on the pane on the right - select devices only.

Comment: Thank a lot! how come it wasn't in the official manual, neither it was anywhere else in the internet? :D

Answer (score 0):

For those that are super newbish (like me), the AVD manager (Android Virtual Device Manager) is under the "Window" tab.